# Styling a specific jQuery Button limited to a particular ID or class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to style a specific jQuery UI button while leaving other buttons alone.

For example, I've tried:

```
.myclass .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active , 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        background: #390 50% 50% repeat-x;
        font-weight: strong;
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

and

```
#myID .ui-state-active, #myID .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active , 
#myID .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
            border: 1px solid #333;
            background: #390 50% 50% repeat-x;
            font-weight: strong;
            color: #FFF;
        }
```

But neither seem to do what I want. When I use my attempts above, the styles are not applied. I think I'm not clear on how to write CSS that's limited to the scope of particular ID or sub-class.

My [fiddle is located here](http://jsfiddle.net/filmotheklown/q8XXL/). It's a simple "Yes/No" button which 'works' but is operating on the global UI styles which I'm trying to avoid.

The html is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tc_all" class='overall'>
<label for="tc_all">No</label>
```

And the jQuery snippet is:

```
  $(function () {
      $("#tc_all").button().click(function () {
          var text = $(this).is(':checked') ? "Yes" : "No"
          $(this).button('option', 'label', text);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#tc_all:checked + label,
#tc_all + .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #390 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5HCnf/5/

Comment: Thanks. By way of explanation, what does the '+' mean. I though css was chained just using whitespace ??

Comment: + selector is next element

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sigma for pointing me in the right direction. I appreciate your help.

Ultimately I ended up wrapping the HTML in a separate DIV to avoid using the "+" selector as its implementation is still buggy on Safari browser according to the [link provided](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

```
<div class='overall'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tc_all">
    <label for="tc_all">No</label>
    </input>
</div>
```

And then used:

```
.overall .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #390 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
.overall .ui-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/filmotheklown/AZ4EW/).